# Angular2 - not able to run the app. throws error

Tags: angular

I am trying to run the `angular2` with my local system. I am getting error as

```
Live reload enabled.
system.src.js:4703 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular2/angualr2.js 404 (Not Found)A @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4703
system.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular2/angualr2.js(…)t @ system.src.js:4703g @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4703
```

But i don't know how to fix this issue. any one help me please?

In case if you need additional information to help, let me know.
Thanks in advance

I am getting error from `ts` file as well:

```
D:\Projects\angular2-seed>tsc --watch app.ts
app.ts(3,1): error TS1148: Cannot compile external modules unless the '--module'
 flag is provided.
app.ts(3,44): error TS2307: Cannot find external module 'angular2/angualr2'.
app.ts(5,1): error TS1205: Decorators are only available when targeting ECMAScri
pt 5 and higher.
message TS6042: Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

I hope it will give some more good idea to predict my issue.

Comment: Is that a typo? 'angualr2.js' in the first error?

Comment: @Aravinda can you see my update in the question?